# Converting ST link v2 to Jlink

Tags: st-link, j-link

Has anyone had any succes with converting a ST link v2 to a Jlink using the software that Segger provides? I have not had any success, even with using instructions they provided and was wondering if any one had any succuess/ guidance.

Comment: What does Segger say?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The conversion tool you're referring to](https://www.segger.com/products/debug-probes/j-link/models/other-j-links/st-link-on-board/) is only intended for use with the on-board ST-Link debuggers included on ST's Discovery and Nucleo development boards. It does not work on standalone ST-Link debuggers.